Can I replace the duo of 4GB DDR3 (1333MHz) cards with 8GB DDR3 cards in my ACER 5750G?
So, I have an old ACER Aspire 5750G-9821 laptop that I use for recording with my Digital Audio Workstation. It's all I use it for, as I have another laptop for my other work.
From the back panel, it has a Crucial 4GB (2Rx8) DDR3 (1333MHz) card, and another card of same value by Hynix. Can I swap them out with two cards that are 8GB DDR3 1333MHz, or will that not work with this laptop?

Your
manual
says this:

System Memory
Dual-channel DDR3 SDRAM support:

Up to 4 GB of DDR3 system memory, upgradable to 8 GB using two soDIMM modules


Your upgrade is not supported. Unsupported upgrades sometimes work
(technology does advance), but the chances are against you.
For example, Crucial says this about
Acer Aspire 5750G-9821 SSD Upgrades:
Your computer's memory capability:
Slots: 2 (2 banks of 1)
Maximum memory: 8GB
Standard memory: 4GB removable

Another maker says the same :
Kingston memory shop.
The conclusion is that no well-known RAM vendor has a solution for
2x8GB, only 2x4GB.
I advice not to waste your money on upgrades that probably won't work.
